# How to install WPMU with composer?

Tags: composer

I am looking for a way to install WPMU and a premium ACF plugin with composer, but have not found any functional way of installing them. The best alternativ I found is to upload them to a private bitbucket and then install them with [Satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md). If someone could point me in to a practical example and/or a better alternative then Satis.

Answer (score 1):

To speak to your primary question (How to install WPMU with composer?) I went down the road of installing [wordpress](https://packagist.org/packages/johnpbloch/wordpress) and then [wp-cli/wp-cli](https://packagist.org/packages/wp-cli/wp-cli) and then using it to do a [multisite-install](http://wp-cli.org/commands/core/multisite-install/).

Answer (score 0):

Composer inherently prefers packages that support it explicitly. It is flexible enough to still work in other cases, but it gets less pleasant.

The options used in practice typically *are* either including premium plugins into version control or re–hosting them yourselves.

After yet another discussion on topic I have also created [Release Belt](https://github.com/Rarst/release-belt) project for this. It aims to easily serve ZIP archives as Composer repository. It isn't much used/tested so far though.